# hide getProperty value

Tags: java, jsp

Is there a way we can prevent getProperty java bean property from printing the value on the jsp page? I am expecting something like HIDDEN input types in html. I want to use that hidden value to do further conditional checks on the jsp page to prevent few other beans that I have on the same page from executing if the conditions were not met.

```
<jsp:useBean id="checkfile" class="org.mypackage.process" scope="page" />
<jsp:setProperty name="checkfile" property="join"/>
<jsp:getProperty name ="checkfile" property="filestat" />
```

My plan:

I am trying to read a file and display the contents on the web page as a report.

I will be using jsp(mostly for the presentation) and java(to read the file contents and returning values to jsp) with the help of beans to achieve this task.

I will be using set/get bean properties on jsp to retrieve the contents from the java file.

My concerns:

My concern is, let's say when the file was not found on that location, bean get property will try to retrieve null value from the java file which I am not comfortable with.

So I want to restrict certain bean properties from executing, if the file doesn't exist.

So I thought of checking to see if the file exists or not, with the above mentioned bean property.

I want to use the ouput(y/N) that I get from bean property on jstl if statement to restrict additional beans from executing if the file doesn't exist on that location.

Hope I am clear.

Thanks

Comment: Some example code, result and what you are expecting from?

Comment: I don't understand; JSTL conditional tags wouldn't print the value.

Comment: Added additional info. thx

Comment: code snippet is not getting added above. I left like 5 spaces as suggested. Doesn't seem to work.